# Make a spendable Bitcoin transaction with a message

Tags: transactions

I am trying to send a bitcoin transaction which encodes a message. I know about OP_RETURN however this makes the transaction un-spendable. I want to make a spendable transaction that contains a message.

This transaction's message needs to be publicly on the blockchain as well.

How can I do this? Any supporting code would also be much appreciated.